# Problema al mostrar un datalist en Android

Tags: html, flask, datalist

Tengo un datalist que muestra todos los datos de una base de datos y esta en un input, para que conforme se vaya escribiendo se escoja la opcion correcta en computadora se me muestra la lista bien pero al ver el sitio web desde el celular, desde ningun navegador muestra las opciones del datalist. Estoy trabajando con flask y los estudiantes es una lista que le mando a la plantilla desde python

```
<label for="Estudiante" name="Estudiante" id="Estudiante" class="texto">Nombre del estudiante</label>
    <input list="Estudiantes" id="seleccion-estudiantes" class="texto">
               <datalist id="Estudiantes">
                        {% for estudiante in estudiantes %}
                  <option value="{{estudiante.nombre}}" class="texto">

                            {% endfor %}

                 </datalist>
```

Intente quitandole la clase pero sigue sin mostrar ningun valor en el movil.

adjunto como se ve la datalist desde el navegador del ordenador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]